# Proving that no two state DFA accept the language L = {$0^i : \forall i \ge 0$} $\lor$ {$^i : \forall i \ge 0$}

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

how do i prove that no DFA with two states can accept the language

$$ L = \{0^i : i \ge 0\} \cup \{ 1^i : i \ge 0\}. $$

I had a lot of troubles coming up with anything that made sense.

Comment: There is only a finite number of DFAs with 2 states. Just enumerate them all.

Comment: I think there is a typo, what do you mean by $^i$ ?

Comment: yeah sorry i ment to have $1^i$

Answer (score 2):

Use Myhill–Nerode theory. Here are four words which are pairwise incomparable:
$$ \epsilon,0,1,01. $$

The following table gives words separating them:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
& \epsilon & 0 & 1 & 01 \\\hline
\epsilon & & 1 & 0 & \epsilon\\\hline
0 & 1 & & 0 & \epsilon\\\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & & \epsilon\\\hline
01 & \epsilon & \epsilon & \epsilon & 
\end{array}
$$

According to Myhill–Nerode theory, every DFA for $L$ must contain at least four states. It is not too hard to construct a DFA containing four states, so four is the minimal number of states.